# MapReduce sort by value in descending order

Tags: sorting, hadoop, mapreduce, pseudocode

I'm trying to write in pseudo code a MapReduce task that returns the items sorted in descending order. For example: for the wordcount task, instead of getting:

```
apple 1
banana 3
mango 2
```

I want the output to be:

```
banana 3
mango 2
apple 1
```

Any ideas of how to do it? I know how to do it in ascending order (replace the keys and value in the mapper job) but not in descending order.

Comment: Just search for "mapreduce secondary sort" and you'll find lots of examples.

Comment: @BinaryNerd This isn't secondary sort if I'm not mistaken. This is just a sort by value which is easier than the secondary sort.

Comment: Sorting by value is a secondary sort in hadoop mapreduce, the primary sort is on the key.

Comment: @BinaryNerd In secondary sort, the sort by the value of the same key. In my case, I don't care what the keys are.

Answer (score 1):

Here you can take help of below reducer code to achieve sorting in descending order .

Assuming you have written mapper and driver code where mapper will produce output as (Banana,1) etc

In reducer we will sum all values for a particular key and put final result in a map then sort the map on the basis of values and write final result in cleanup function of reduce.

Please see below code for further understadnind:

```
public class Word_Reducer extends Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable> {
    // Change access modifier as per your need 
    public Map<String , Integer > map = new LinkedHashMap<String , Integer>();
    public void reduce(Text key , Iterable<IntWritable> values ,Context context)
    { 
    // write logic for your reducer 
    // Enter reduced values in map for each key
    for (IntWritable value : values ){
         // calculate "count" associated with each word 
    }
    map.put(key.toString() , count); 
}

public void cleanup(Context context){ 
    //Cleanup is called once at the end to finish off anything for reducer
    //Here we will write our final output
    Map<String , Integer>  sortedMap = new HashMap<String , Integer>();    
    sortedMap = sortMap(map);

    for (Map.Entry<String,Integer> entry = sortedMap.entrySet()){
        context.write(new Text(entry.getKey()),new IntWritable(entry.getValue()));
    }
}

public Map<String , Integer > sortMap (Map<String,Integer> unsortMap){
    Map<String ,Integer> hashmap = new LinkedHashMap<String,Integer>();
    int count=0;
    List<Map.Entry<String,Integer>> list = new 
    LinkedList<Map.Entry<String,Integer>>(unsortMap.entrySet());
    //Sorting the list we created from unsorted Map
    Collections.sort(list , new Comparator<Map.Entry<String,Integer>>(){
        public int compare (Map.Entry<String , Integer> o1 , Map.Entry<String , Integer> o2 ){
            //sorting in descending order
            return o2.getValue().compareTo(o1.getValue());
        }
    });

    for(Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : list){
        // only writing top 3 in the sorted map 
        if(count>2)
            break;
        hashmap.put(entry.getKey(),entry.getValue());
    }
    return hashmap ; 
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I understood from your answer how to sort the values of the same key. I don't think the Map of all the strings and integers would be saved through this all process. Also, how would I know when to call the cleanup function?

Comment: Cleanup function is called once automatically at the end of reduce task.

Comment: Ok , good. What about the first thing I mentioned? I don't think the Map of the keys and values is saved and being updated through the whole process, I think the only variable that does that is Counter. Am I wrong?

Comment: I didnt get what you meant by sort the values of the same key
and during computation all maps will be in memory.

Comment: What I want is to sort the by the values no matter what the key is. You set a linkedhashmap: public Map<String , Integer > map = new LinkedHashMap<String , Integer>();
and said it would collect all the values for all the keys, right? so, I don't think it does.

Comment: Reduce function is called for every unique key and everytime its called it will count then add K,V to map. Same map will be passed to sort function then returned in Cleanup function and then written to output . 
Run the code for further understanding.