# MapReduce output ordering in Java8

Tags: java, hadoop, java-8, reducers

I try to use the solution for sorting the output of my reducer in `Hadoop` as mentioned in this question:

[MapReduce sort by value in descending order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44679841/mapreduce-sort-by-value-in-descending-order)

This one had some conflicts with Java8, so I resolved them as follow:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Iterator;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;

import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Comparator;

public class HourlyTweetsReducer extends Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable> {

    private IntWritable result = new IntWritable();
    public Map<String , Integer> map = new LinkedHashMap<String , Integer>();

    public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values, Context context)
    throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        int sum = 0;
        for (IntWritable value : values) {
            sum += value.get();
        }
        map.put(key.toString() , sum);

        result.set(sum);
        context.write(key, result);
    }

    public void cleanup(Context context){
        //Cleanup is called once at the end to finish off anything for reducer
        //Here we will write our final output
        Map<String , Integer>  sortedMap = new HashMap<String , Integer>();
        sortedMap = sortMap(map);

        for (Map.Entry<String,Integer> entry : sortedMap.entrySet()){
            context.write(new Text(entry.getKey()),new IntWritable(entry.getValue()));
        }
    }

    public Map<String , Integer > sortMap (Map<String,Integer> unsortMap){

        Map<String ,Integer> hashmap = new HashMap<String,Integer>();
        int count=0;
        List<Map.Entry<String,Integer>> list = new LinkedList<Map.Entry<String,Integer>>(unsortMap.entrySet());
        //Sorting the list we created from unsorted Map
        Collections.sort(list , new Comparator<Map.Entry<String,Integer>>(){
            public int compare (Map.Entry<String , Integer> o1 , Map.Entry<String , Integer> o2 ){
                //sorting in descending order
                return o2.getValue().compareTo(o1.getValue());
            }
        });

        for(Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : list){
            // only writing top 3 in the sorted map
            // if(count>2)
            // break;
            hashmap.put(entry.getKey(),entry.getValue());
        }

        return hashmap ;
    }

}
```

The problem is that the output is not sorted after running the job:

```
11  1041557
14  1304166
17  1434978
2   733462
20  1288767
23  1677571
5   460629
8   497403
11  1041557
23  1677571
2   733462
14  1304166
5   460629
17  1434978
8   497403
20  1288767
```

How we can solve it?

Comment: *HourlyTweets.java uses or overrides a deprecated API* is this a library you use or your own program?

Comment: It's my own programme based on Hadoop

Comment: well it just states in the error message: `unreported exception IOException; must be caught or declared to be thrown` in `HourlyTweetsReducer.java:45`

Comment: Just use a nice `try` on stated `45` line

Comment: Are you developing in Notepad? A decent IDE will probably even give you options what to do.

Comment: I'm using Atom for editing code

Comment: get an IDE then something like IntelliJ/Netbeans/eclipse they help you a lot!

Comment: It works. but the result is not sorted anyway! :(

Comment: Which “conflicts with Java8” did you have to resolve, or, if this is irrelevant to your question, why do you mention them and even tag you question with `[java-8]`? Besides that, your entire `sortMap` step is obsolete when you store into a `HashMap` which is specified to not provide any ordering. You have to use a `LinkedHashMap` as *target* map to remember the insertion order, but that’s not Java 8 specific. In contrast, the use of `LinkedList` here has no point and is extremely inefficient. You should use an `ArrayList` instead.

Comment: @Holger I used an example (that is mentioned in the question) which is written in Java 7, so I just tried to get it work correctly by Java8 and changed it a bit, but as I couldn't got the right result I thought the problem lied there.

Comment: Since the linked example *does* use a `LinkedHashMap` as target, it’s not surprising that your code breaks, however, this has nothing to do with Java 8 and there is also no imaginable problem that your change could fix. Besides that, the code of the linked answer is of poor quality, and in its posted form doesn’t even compile, regardless of the Java version, so you should clean up carefully. Besides the already mentioned discouraged use of `LinkedList`, there are unused variables and objects cluttering the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’m not going to judge whether this code needs additional steps to ensure correctness in the context of Hadoop’s Map/Reduce.

But one obvious mistake is that at the beginning of `sortMap`, there is the line

```
Map<String ,Integer> hashmap = new HashMap<String,Integer>();
```

which creates a map that does not maintain any specific order, so filling it in sorted order has no effect. It should be a `LinkedHashMap` instead, as in the code of the linked Q&A.

Note that this is independent to the map created by the caller:

```
Map<String , Integer>  sortedMap = new HashMap<String , Integer>();
sortedMap = sortMap(map);
```

here, the reference to the created map gets overwritten by the result of `sortMap` and thus, the map instance entirely obsolete. But since all you are going to do, is iterating once over the sorted map to perform one action, you don’t need to copy the sorted list to a result `Map` at all, as you could perform the action already by iterating over the list:

```
public void cleanup(Context context) {
    //Cleanup is called once at the end to finish off anything for reducer
    //Here we will write our final output

    List<Map.Entry<String,Integer>> list = new ArrayList<>(map.entrySet());

    Collections.sort(list, Map.Entry.comparingByValue(Comparator.reverseOrder()));

    for(Map.Entry<String,Integer> entry: list) {
        context.write(new Text(entry.getKey()), new IntWritable(entry.getValue()));
    }
}
```

This uses Java 8’s `Map.Entry.comparingByValue(Comparator.reverseOrder())` builtin comparators. If Java 7 compatibility is required, use the comparator code shown in your question,

```
new Comparator<Map.Entry<String, Integer>>() {
    public int compare(Map.Entry<String, Integer> o1, Map.Entry<String, Integer> o2) {
        //sorting in descending order
        return o2.getValue().compareTo(o1.getValue());
    }
}
```

Note that this code uses `ArrayList` instead of `LinkedList`, as all three operations you are going to do with it, 1) initializing it with the contents of the map’s entry set, 2) sorting it in-place and 3) iterating over it, work substantially faster with `ArrayList`. That’s especially true for step 2) in Java 8.

Answer (score 1):

I see two options here:

1. just use a single reducer. This requires that all the data can fit in the memory of a single machine. Then, the input of the single reducer will be sorted in order of key (what you want).
2. Use **TotalOrderPartitioner**
   https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.4.1/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/partition/TotalOrderPartitioner.html

it enforces an additional stage in the MapReduce pipeline to partition the elements into sorted buckets.

Here is a example(not mine) that shows how to use TotalOrderPartioner: https://gist.github.com/asimjalis/e5627dc2ff2b23dac70b

Comment: Just to explain about option 1. The problem I see is not in code but the number of reducers that run. If multiple reducers runs then they will distribute your data is multiple buckets and will sort data of each bucket and merging them later, thus causing the problem

Comment: thank you, it is a part of main job file rather than mapper or reducer, right?

Comment: Well, do it where u define the number of reducers, If you have not defined them  then number will be decided according to the size of data. It is a good practice to define them in main job file, but make sure the data can fit in the memory of single machine.
If not go with option 2, it will work for sure.